# Coldfusion - Updating dynamic form fields

Tags: dynamic, coldfusion

Thanks for the help in advance!

My application allows the users to create dynamic questions, which have n number of dynamic answers related to the question.

The page allowing the user to build these is complete, and creating these works perfectly.

I am stuck on the most efficient way to build the ability to update. Normally during an update, I would just drop the fields / relationships and rebuild them. This isn't an option in this application, as once an answer is entered, I need to preserve it for reporting purposes.

So, during an update, I need to recognize which answers are new, and insert those - while not updating the older answers at all.

Need some help thinking this one through, thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

To make something like this happen, I generally have a hidden field next to each field I'm going to update that contains its ID. If the matching ID for a field is "0", then I know that it's a new item versus an item that already exists and needs to be updated. So when you loop through your FORM structure, run updates on non-zero IDs, and inserts on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a similar approach as Dan, but included the ID in the field name itself. For example, if I had three answer fields, one of which is new, the names might be 'Answer210', 'Answer211', and 'Answer0'.

When I process the form, I can loop over each field, grab the number after the text - 'Answer' - and process the data accordingly. What you end up doing is something like this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfif isDefined("form.FIELDNAMES")>

    <cfloop index="x" list = "#form.fieldnames#">  
        <cfif findNoCase('answer',x) NEQ 0>
            <cfset varInteger = replaceNoCase(x,'Answer','')>
            <cfif varInteger EQ 0>
                Insert Answer text: #form[x]# with ID of #varInteger#<br />
            <cfelse>
                Update Answer text: #form[x]# with ID of #varInteger#<br />
            </cfif>     
        </cfif>  
    </cfloop>

</cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Keep in mind the processing can be handled any number of ways... this is a proof of concept.